# Inspect code shows error in 'sample.json' but no error message is shown. How do I know whats broken?

Tags: json, android-studio

I created an app in android studio, after testing it several times I published it on play store. But thereafter the app started crashing. So to fix it, I edited my project and then when I ran 'inspect code' I got an error in 'sample.json'. But the error message is not shown.

[image: Android studio screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, what fixed it for me was that I located my 'sample.json' file and deleted it. Then I cleaned my project (Build->Clean Project), and the error was gone.